# Metal/OpenGL: How to set vertex buffer only once?

Tags: swift, metal

I have gone through https://www.raywenderlich.com/146414/metal-tutorial-swift-3-part-1-getting-started. For every frame

```
renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, at: 0)
renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(texture, at: 0)
```

is done. But vertex and texture data is never changed. Only Uniform matrices change. My object being rendered contains `8*4*4*4*4` triangles(yep, its a sphere). I could only get 4FPS. I am skeptical about setting the vertexBuffer every frame.

Its done similarly in OpenGL tutorials http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/

In OpenGL I could pull out vertex/texture buffer binding out of the render loop. But in Metal `MTLRenderCommandEncoder` needs `CAMetalDrawable` which is fetched for every frame.

Comment: What device and software version are you running your app on? As a completely wild guess, are you using the `drawPrimitives(type:vertexStart:vertexCount:instanceCount:)` method and passing anything other than `1` as the instance count?

Comment: yep, `instanceCount: 8*4*4*4*4`. iPhone 5s with iOS 10.3.1

Comment: And what is `vertexCount`? Odds are pretty good you should be setting `instanceCount` to 1.

Comment: its 3*8*4*4*4*4

Comment: yeah making `instanceCount: 1` has put it at 60FPS

Comment: don't blame me, thats what its there in the raywanderlich's tutorial!

Comment: It's not your fault, and it's a common point of confusion. That tutorial should probably omit the `instanceCount` parameter entirely, since it's not actually doing instanced drawing (and neither are you). Just to be clear, though: when you're just drawing one object, the number of triangles is inferred from the `vertexCount` parameter, and `instanceCount` should always be 1.

Comment: For my own use case I noticed that replacing `view.layer.addSublayer(metalLayer)` with `view.layer = metalLayer` would halve the CPU usage, if you don't need to do anything else with the layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically use a new render command encoder for each frame. Anything you did with the previous render command encoder, like setting vertex buffers or fragment textures, is "lost" when that encoder is ended and you drop any references to it. So, yes, you need to set buffers and textures again.

However, that should not be expensive. Both of those methods just put a *reference* to the buffer or texture into a table. It's cheap. If you haven't modified their contents on the CPU, no data has to be copied. It shouldn't cause any state compilation, either. (Apple has said a design goal of Metal is to avoid any implicit state compilation. It's all explicit, such as when creating a render pipeline state object from a render pipeline descriptor.)

You need to profile your app to figure out what's limiting your frame rate, rather than guessing.

Comment: "If you haven't modified their contents on the CPU, no data has to be copied" You already said no data will be copied but its referenced in your answer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797198/in-metal-does-setting-vertex-and-fragment-buffer-to-same-mtlbuffer-copies-it-to assuming `GPU` and `CPU` share the memory.